# Asset images not showing on release mode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, assets

I'm hoping someone can give me a suggestion that helps.

I am updating an app I developed for my company 2 years ago, the issue is that almost all of the images in the assets folder do not show on screen when the app is launched manually by a user. When I run the app through XCode all my images appear normally, whereas when I tap on the app from the home screen most of the images do not load. The UI is still set and you can click on buttons that have image icons, but there is simply no image there. I am running the latest XCode 12.1 and supporting iOS 12 and up. Ive tried running this on the simulator and on devices running iOS 14, the same issue happens on both.

I have spent several days trying to figure out the problem, and haven't found many references online aside from issues with iOS 7 and with react-native.

#### What I've done

- remove target membership for the assets and reset to project's target
- removed and reset the asset catalog from "Copy Bundle Resources"
- cleaned (many times) and rebuilt the project
- deleted and replaced the asset catalog
- Moved all project files to another project (issue kept happening)
- Create a minimal reproducible example by just moving the images to another project, but assets behaved normally in that case
- deleted the app from devices/simulators and re-built
- quit & re-opened Xcode and the simulator
- Gone through build settings comparing to another working project and tried to mimic settings

Image example:

Home page tab bar when ran from Xcode:

[image: Home page tab bar when ran from XCode]

Home page tab bar when ran from user input (it's just empty, but the tab bar items are clickable)

[image: Home page tab bar when ran from user input (it's just empty, but the tab bar items are still clickable)]

I would appreciate any suggestions that someone can give as this issue has been driving my head in for several days now.

Thank you,

Alan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update since I cannot delete the question anymore. My issue was with one of the pods I had in the project called Gifu, with iOS 14 a UIImageView extension messed up basically all the Image Views in my project, so if someone is also having this issue a suggestion is to go through any of your pods that affect your images and see if any issues have arisen with them, they probably would've been listed in the issues on the pods github page.

Answer (score 2):

I am really sorry for posting it as an answer but I am new to stackOverFlow:) I still don't have enough reputation to comment but really want to help you!

Have you tried setting rendering setting as Template?

([image]Render as Template Image)

Comment: You don't need to apologize. Welcome to Stack Overflow. My problem turned out to be with a pod I was using called Gifu. I should've noticed that prior to posting, but now I can't delete the post. Thanks anyway :)